# How to use Polygon2D node in Godot to create a regular polygon?

Tags: polygon, godot, 2d-games

I am new to Godot and I want to create a regular polygon shape.
I don't quite get how Polygon2D node works.
I generated a list of points in the script of the node and passed it as the value of the polygon parameter as follows:

```
extends Polygon2D
func polar2cartesian(r, theta):
    var x = r * cos(theta)
    var y = r * sin(theta)
    return Vector2(x, y)
    
    
func createPoly(n):
    var r = 200 # radius
    var points = []

    for i in range(n):
        var theta = PI*2 / n * i # get the angle for the current iteration, in radians
        var point = polar2cartesian(r, theta)
        points.append(point)
    points.append(points[0])
    return points

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    self.polygon =createPoly(5)


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass
```

Nothing happens
What am I missing?
How to use the Polygon2D node.

Also, how to create a nice Circle (with antialiasing)

Comment: Your code should be working. A regular pentagon should appear when you run the game. I'm guessing the `Polygon2D` is not visible due to its position in the game world or something else. Does its color blend with the background? Is it not within the area seen by the `Camera2D`?

Comment: oh yeah! you're right! Thank you! So stupid of me